Black rectangle when changing volume, when Opera browser is running
Even if the browser window is minimized, and I change the volume this black rectangle will appear in the left top corner, and stay for a significant amount of time.
Is there some way to turn it off ?


This can be disabled in Opera:

In the address bar, go to chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling
Set Hardware Media Key Handling to disabled
Restart Opera

